# VBA move value to adjecent cell

Tags: excel, vba

OK its just simple two lines of Code that for some reason don't work as expected. I'm sure its something simple but I can't put my finger on it:

```
Dim Series as Range
Dim i      as Integer

Set Series = Range("A1:B1")
i = 1

' Following two lines apparently don't do anything
' I would have expected them to move value of cell B1 to A1, and make B1 blank
Series.Value2(1, i) = Series.Value2(1, i + 1)
Series.Value2(1, i + 1) = ""
```

Example:

```
   A  B
1  "" 1
```

Desired Result:

```
   A  B
1  1  ""
```

Again I know its a very simple( and simplified) code but I just can't figure it out.

Comment: That's not how I would do that task; but I can confirm it does not work with Excel 2007, and I'm not sure why.  In safe mode, the code causes Excel to crash (shut down).  In normal mode, the first time I got a `Stack Overflow` error.  The second time it crashed.

Comment: Thanks for trying it out. That being said how would you move that cell value? I'm open to sugestions.

Comment: I'll post an answer with one solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up defining another Range inside the problematic one and I used Offset to refernce Cell next to that Range, it not very elegant but it solves the problem.

```
Dim Series  as Range
Dim S_Point as Range
Dim i       as Integer

Set Series = Range("A1:B1")
i = 1

Set S_Point = Cells( Series.Row, i)
S_Point.Value2 = S_Point.Offset(0,1).Value2
S_Point.Offset(0,1).Value2 = ""
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code above, I would change it as below to accomplish the same task, referring to individual cells of the range object:

```
Series(i).Value2 = Series(i + 1).Value2
Series(i + 1).Value2 = ""
```

Comment: Actualy I did this because your version produces 'Object Defined Error number 1004'. That being said I absolutelly agree that your and Seteven Matrin's version seems more natural.

Comment: it works fine here with no errors. Did you define Series the way you did in your original code?

Comment: In my original code 'Series' is initialized in a in a follwoinng way 'For Each Series in All_Series.Rows' All_Sereis is initalized with Selection. Nontheles Excel sees Series.Value2(as well as all other relevant arrays in Range)  as two dimensional array.

Comment: That is not helpful. If Series is a range object, then Each Series will represent a row, not a cell.

Answer (score 1):

Why have you put the () after the value2 ?

This works just fine...

```
Series(1, i).Value2 = Series(1, i + 1).Value2
Series(1, i + 1).Value2 = ""
```